# What a powerful attacks you have just done there

Tags: grammar

Let's you are playing COC(Clash of clans). Then you have just made 2 powerful attacks in clan war(2 different bases in just 1 clanwar), hence your clanmate complimented you on that.

> **What** **a** powerful **attacks** you have just done there dude! Exceptional!

I am aware of how to use ''articles'' BUT not quite, coz' I have included the **''what a''** at the very beginning **+attacks**(plural form as you have done 2 different attacks but within just 1 day)

Moreover, is the highlighted sentence grammatical?

Comment: You need a or s, not both: a powerful attack, or powerful attacks. Also, to attack or make an attack or even execute an attack. "Do" is not so great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct.

You cannot use "a" and "attacks" together because it is more than one attack. You may say

"What powerful attacks you have just done"

Comment: This *"What powerful attacks you have just done"* is what I worry about, it seems like a question now. That is why I made it **"what a"** instead of just **"what"**.

Comment: @JohnArvin - If you wanted to make it a question, you'd invert the subject and auxiliary verb: "What powerful attacks **have you** just done?" Native English speakers would not mistake the sentence Amber Hopkins supplied as a question.